# How to get all records in a table not in another table in a Sequel Ruby model

Tags: ruby, sequel

The idea is to return model instances of the table_1 model where the id's of table_1 do not exist in table_2 where another_id has a value. This is so I can use those instances and the data contained within elsewhere

```
def self.my_method(another_id:)
  result = DB["SELECT t1.* FROM table_1 t1 WHERE t1.id NOT IN (SELECT t2.id 
  FROM table_2 t2 WHERE t2.another_id = #{another_id})"]

  result_array = []
  result.each do |row| 
   result_array << self.find(id: row[:id])
  end

 result_array
end
```

I have models for both table_1 and table_2

This works but it feels very clunky and probably very inefficient as for every id that is returned I am rebuilding an instance of each table_1 model by looking at the database again.

How would this be done in a typically Sequel way using the methods available on the Model/Dataset. From my viewpoint I am struggling with how I pull together the various pieces of syntax to do this

Comment: Try asking at https://groups.google.com/g/sequel-talk?pli=1

Comment: The Sequel [README](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html#label-A+Short+Example) has good examples of simple SQLite DB code that would be a good starting point.

Comment: As @Eyeslandic said, the Sequel-Talk list is a good source.

Comment: I will take on board the feedback and look where suggested